# Notes in a Bookmark for Android Mobile Browsers

Tags: android, chrome, note-taking, bookmark

I'm am looking for an Android application that would allow me to edit/add bookmarks with the ability to attach notes to them.

**I am open to all solutions meaning cost does not matter. The question is rather when can it be done.**

The purpose of this is to better organize my bookmarks. Please see below for a picture of what I am talking about:

[image: Screenshot of Bookmark Editor]

The only solution that I have come up with is when I use chrome browser, by typing in the "Name" form  in "Edit Bookmark." Is there a browser or application that would contain a notes section for a given bookmark?

Comment: I included this is my edit. Izzy you are very helpful, where can I find the proper etiquette so I can make my post more useful for the community in terms of increasing the probability of getting my questions answered and reduce headaches for moderators/admins like yourself? Should I ask meta of group first before posting? Sorry, I am brand new.

Comment: Thanks for asking that! You could simply *check* Meta, as most things are already there. Our master examples would be [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) – other important relevant posts are [tagged `faq`](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) to make them easy to find. Also, our [help] is a good source. The latter two items are valid for most SE sites, by the way. Enjoy your stay at SR – I hope we can provide you with the recommendations you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a little research for you, I think I found a near perfect match: **[NEO Bookmark](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seyeonsoft.neobookmark.lite)**.

[image: Edit bookmark] [image: Navigate Bookmarks] [image: Organize Categories]
<sup>Edit / Navigate bookmarks, organize categories with *NEO* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seyeonsoft.neobookmark.lite); click images for larger variants)</sup>

The screenshot should visualize how this app meets your requirements:

- **edit/add bookmarks:** Yes.
- **ability to attach notes to them:** Yes (see the "Memo" field in the 1st screenshot)
- **better organize my bookmarks:** Definitely (see the other two screenshots)

*NEO* lets you categorize your bookmarks, easily navigate those categories (2nd screenshot), and easily rearrange categories by drag-and-drop (3rd screenshot) – which is even more than you asked for. Try the free app, and when you're happy with it you can "go pro" and buy [the pro addon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ululu.android.apps.my_bookmark.pro). Otherwise (I don't think that will happen, but "curiosity" counts as well) you might wish to check for alternatives. For this, I'm just setting up a [list of bookmark managers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser#group_1087) which you are welcome to browse.

Comment: I appreciate the research, Izzy. I just realized that I did not include, in my question, that it would happen inside the MOBILE BROWSER. This tool is awesome for bookmark organization, as an application in itself. I have yet to find something that does what I really seek. I just discovered pinboard. Thank you very much for your time and effort and I apologize for being stupid!

Comment: Well Ted, you could ask a new question (pointing here for context and to avoid "close-as-dupe" votes), describing you want exactly this but *inside a browser.* I specifically skipped browsers as I didn't think you wanted them. Also be welcome to see my [Web Browser](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser) listings :)